# Solving a second order differential equation by substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation
$$4x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2} + y = 8 \sqrt{x} + 8\sqrt{x}\ln x, \ \ x>0.$$

---

I am supposed to transform this $t = \ln x.$ Then, we have that
$$x \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} (\ln x)} = \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t},$$
and
$$x\frac{\mathrm{d} ^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}  ^2 y}{\mathrm{d} t ^2} - \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t}.$$
Then, we can write the differential equation as
$$4y'' - 4y' + y = 8e^{(1/2)t}(1+t).$$
Now, I can solve the homogenous equation by just setting $4r^2 - 4r + 1 = 0,$ so I have
$$y(x) = c_1e^{(1/2)t} + c_2te^{(1/2)t}.$$
But how do I finish the problem? I don't really know how to include that function.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your calculation.  You don't have $4r^2-r+1=0$.

Comment: @user10354138 I believe this is correct. I have the solutions, I just don't have an explanation.

Comment: No, you should have $\require{color}x^{\color{red}2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2}-\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and $4{\color{red}(}\ddot{y}-\dot{y}{\color{red})}+y=\dots$, so the auxiliary equation is not $4r^2-r+1=0$ but $4r^2-{\color{red}4}r+1=0$.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes! Sorry, I wrote it down wrong. My question still stands, however :)

Comment: So now look for particular solutions $y_p=At^2 e^{t/2}+Bt^3 e^{t/2}$.  Note the extra factors of $t$ to move it above the $c_1 e^{t/2}+c_2te^{t/2}$ in the solution to homogeneous DE.

Comment: @user10354138 Ok, I get that. But how do I find $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$4y'' - 4y' + y = 8e^{(1/2)t}(1+t)$$ which has the homogenous solution

$$y_h({\color{red}{t}})= c_1e^{\frac{t}{2}} + c_2te^{\frac{t}{2}}$$

and for the particular solution we try a solution of the form

$$y_{p}(t)=e^{\frac{t}{2}}\left(At^{2}+Bt^3\right)$$ so

$$y'_{p}(t)=e^{\frac{t}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}At^2+\frac{1}{2}Bt^3+2At+3Bt^2\right)$$
$$y''_{p}(t)=e^{\frac{t}{2}}\left(2A+2At+6Bt+\frac{A}{4}t^2+3Bt^2+\frac{B}{4}t^3\right)$$

and substituting into the equation we have

$$e^{\frac{t}{2}}\left(8A+8At+24Bt+At^2+12Bt^2+Bt^3-2At^2-2Bt^3-8At-12Bt^2+At^2+Bt^3\right)$$
$$=8e^{\frac{t}{2}}\left(A+3Bt\right)=8e^{\frac{t}{2}}\left(1+t\right)$$
$$\implies A=1,\space B=\frac{1}{3}$$